# select query based on priority

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table

```
Id  createdonutc 
1    2014-05-29 10:14:00.240
2    2014-05-29 10:16:58.587
3    2014-06-01 11:32:54.140
4    2014-05-29 10:48:40.427
6    2014-06-01 2:1:54.140
```

I want to get the data with orderby date only(no time) desc

```
Id  createdonutc                    rank

3    2014-06-01 11:32:54.140         1
6    2014-06-01 2:1:54.140           1
1    2014-05-29 10:14:00.240         2
2    2014-05-29 10:16:58.587         2
4    2014-05-29 10:48:40.427         2
```

i tried:

```
SELECT
    id, 
    P.createdonutc,  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cast(p.[CreatedOnUtc] AS DATE) ORDER BY cast(p.[CreatedOnUtc] AS DATE) desc) as num
FROM
    news p
ORDER BY num
```

it shows no change on the result.How can i get it to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT
    id, 
    P.createdonutc,  
    Dense_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY cast(p.[CreatedOnUtc] AS DATE) desc) as num
FROM
    news p
ORDER BY num
```

Answer (score 0):

`Row_Number` generate a different number for every row, even when the values are equal, to get what you want you need to use `DENSE_RANK`

```
SELECT id, createdonutc
     , dense_rank() OVER (order by cast(createdonutc as date) DESC)
FROM   News
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0c7ab/3)</kbd>